# Making a game, should i load all the sprite animation images before start the game?

Tags: javascript, canvas

It's better to load all animations sprites in a array before start or do this that also works fine too:

```
var frame = new Image();

function update(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    ctx.drawImage(frame, x, y, width, height)
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", key => {
    if(key.keyCode == 65 || key.keyCode == 37){
        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            frame.src = "./walkingspriteframes/frame"+i+".png";
        };
    }
})
```

Comment: Time is very important so if do game, i load whole what i need (it depends on loaded object size) before playing game

Comment: Pre-loading them all will probably be the easiest thing for you to do. You might also consider looking into "sprite-sheets". Basically, you put multiple images into a single file, then display a small part of the large image-file instead of all of the small one. This makes the game even more efficient - you have a single image-file header and can take advantage of compression across multiple images, rather than just sections within a single one. Stackoverflow uses that technique, as seen here: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=fd9ee425c546

Comment: @enhzflep I knew that but I didn't know how to split the sprite so I just did it like in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preloading is usually the best thing to do (at least for frequently used assets, such as animation sprites), for these reasons:

- Fetching resources over a network has a latency cost associated with it. When you are doing it during a game that should be running at 30-60 frames per second and responding to user inputs quickly, it may significantly degrade the player's experience.
- If you are loading images on demand, you will need to consider the possibility that the image loading may fail (because of a network failure, for example) and what should be done in such a situation. An advantage of preloading is that you can choose to not let your game start if important assets are not available.

In addition, the code you have posted will not work as you may have expected it to. It will only display `frame3.png`. This is because JavaScript in the browser is single-threaded: `update` and the keydown listener will never run concurrently, so the `ctx.drawImage` call in `update` will not see `frame.src` set to `frame1.png` or `frame2.png`.

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't thought about this part of the network